# What are the alternatives to AeroGarden

Tags: indoors, light, hydroponic

I'm looking for an indoor hydroponic system and I've found the [AeroGarden](http://www.aerogarden.com/) family which looks great but I'd like to check the alternatives. Are there systems similar to this? Important features for me:

- Relatively compact size
- Adjustable lamp height
- Adjustable light cycle
- Automatic pump cycle
- Silent pump

Comment: I'd also be curious to know - I have a friend with the AeroGarden, and she loves it, but it is quite pricey...

Answer (score 6):

I've built my own aero tank from an Ikea storage box and a 24V pond fogger. I started with [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjWLyA-w4Bo) and made a few tweaks and refinements over time, and the thing works quite well. Since there is no pump, and the fogger is perfectly quiet, all you can hear is a soft tinkling of water drops (the fogger knocks up a spray as well as fog). Add a grow lamp of your choosing (or sunlight), and done.

[image: Selfmade aeroponics]

One thing I added was a styrofoam float to keep the fogger at ideal depth no matter the water level (which you can either make yourself or find on eBay).

[image: Fogger float]

The whole setup costs around £30 to build and has worked very well. The fogger lasts for about 6-9 months before it needs replacing (at about £12).

Comment: Very nice! This looks great. Have you grown any plants to maturity in it?

Comment: Yep, here's some lettuce: https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0i1w1o0Q0H0R1p2F3u2z/lettuce.JPG

Answer (score 3):

Well with a little research you could relatively easily build/customize your own.  There are plans online for things like that.  Are you planning on growing the typical aerogarden plants?  I'd check the hydroponic websites and if there's a store in your area go talk to the owner.  They usually carry catalogues for all the things they don't carry.